# Url without controllerName

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to hide the controller name from URL. I am using the below code.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Customized",
    url: "{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This works perfecly.

but only works when i type

```
http :// domain/ActionName
```

otherwise, I still able to see

```
http :// domainname/controller/action
```

Is there any way to `http ://domain/ActionName` even if user tried to type

```
http :// domainname/controller/action
```

Comment: How do you plan to differentiate actions?

Comment: You only have one controller ? (`HomeController`)

Comment: yes only one controller

Comment: What about removing your default routing ? This will force users to type `http://DomainName/ActionName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one Controller (`Home`) I guess you can have only one route definition ( assuming all your actions share the same parameter pattern) :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Customized",
    url: "{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially do something hacky like check the actual path once you got into the action and if it's not the right path, then redirect to the right path, but that technically causes two requests and could hammer your server if done frequently enough.

MVC Routing employs short-circuit logic to match the request path with an appropriate action. It doesn't care that there may be a "better" route that the user should have used, it only cares that it found a match.